# Refactor ruby condition with params

Tags: ruby, refactoring, conditional-statements, reek

I'd like to know if there is a simpler way to do this condition in ruby

**My Condition :**

```
a = params[:smth].to_s == 'foo' ? 'foo2' : params[:smth].to_s
```

The problem of that condition, that reek throw warning of using `params[:smth]` 2 times, there is one possibility to assign `params[:smth]` to variable, but maybe you know smarter way?

Comment: Why I s `to_s` necessary? What is `params[:smth].class`?

Comment: @CarySwoveland Thank you for remark `to_s` isn't necessary.

Comment: What's the rationale behind this condition? Why do you want to replace `"foo"` with `"foo2"`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd probably write it like this:

```
a = params[:smth].to_s
a = 'foo2' if a == 'foo'
```

Comment: Author use to_s. maybe the smth key is not a string

Comment: @LukasBaliak: ah, it was added later :) Still, doesn't change much.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev "there is one possibility to assign params[:smth] to variable" is there in the OP :)

Comment: @webster: depends what he meant by that. Maybe something like `b = params[:smth]; a = b.to_s == 'foo' ? 'foo2' : b.to_s` :)

Comment: Communicating intent is important, and this code definitely wins over the accepted answer in that regard.

Comment: I agree with @Max

Comment: Thank you, for answer, but this solution I used before many times, @LukasBaliak answer was more interesting, but now I see there are no better way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use lambda for this. **But the set varialbe before is the best way.**

like this:

```
p =->(s){s == 'foo' ? 'foo2' : s}

params = {smth: 'foo'}
a = p.(params[:smth].to_s)
# => "foo2"

params = {smth: 'bar'}
a = p.(params[:smth].to_s)
# => "bar"
```